# Phi before datasheet timing value

Tags: datasheet, timing

I have just come across [this data sheet](http://www.vox-power.com/pdf/nevo600_user_manual_ra.pdf) that specifies values from a timing diagram as

> \$t_1\$ φ 300 ms, \$t_2\$ φ 50 ms, \$t_3\$ φ 25 ms, \$t_4\$ φ 15 ms,
>   \$t_5\$ = 5 ms (minimum), \$t_6\$ φ 100 ms

The φ seems like maybe some kind of equivalence symbol.  Any definite meaning?

Comment: Can you post a link to the actual datasheet?

Comment: page 6: [http://www.vox-power.com/pdf/nevo600_user_manual_ra.pdf](http://www.vox-power.com/pdf/nevo600_user_manual_ra.pdf)

Comment: The context suggests "approximately" (\$\approx\$) but I've never seen a \$\varphi\$ symbol used for this purpose.

Comment: THey probably didn't have that character in their font library. I use ~ when I don't have the ≈ and only use phi for angles e.g. LED beamwidth now where is my phi ¡™£¢∞§¶•ªº–≠«‘“πøˆ¨¥†®´∑åß∂ƒ©˙∆˚¬…æ÷≥≤µ˜∫√ç≈Ω¸˛Ç◊ı˜Â¯˘ÆÚÒÔÓ˝ÏÎÍŒ„´‰ˇÁ¨ˆØ∏”’±—‚·°‡ﬂﬁ›‹€

Comment: @Tony Stewart: here it is: Φ φ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so to sum up in an answer:

It most likely means "approximately" and was maybe used due to a lack of the correct symbol (≈) in the font set used for the document